# Return Double if UITextField is empty or nil

Tags: xcode, swift3, uitextfield

Everything I do, try ahhhhhh, gives me fatal error found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Yes I know you should never force unwrap but xcode forces me to put the damn `!`!

I have an input field that I called from another function which **must** return a `Double`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

// viewDidLoad():
inputField.keyboardType = .decimalPad

// Fail!
func returnDouble() -> Double {
 guard let f = inputField.text else {return 0.00 }
 return Double(f)! 
}

// Fail!
func returnDouble() -> Double {
 // if let f = (inputField.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {} // mega fail
 guard let f = inputField.text else {return 0.00 }
 return Double(f)! 
}

// Fail!
func returnDouble() -> Double {
    if let f = inputField.text {
        return Double(f)!
    } else {
        return 0.00
    }
}
```

Im lost at this point. If the input field is blank, I should get `0.0` or if not then the inputted value. I've also tried `inputField.hasText` but I'm forced to add `!` and it also crashes. Any second eye, please?

Comment: Did you connect the textfield outlet to the text field in the storyboard?

Comment: @Sweeper yes I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound really counter-intuitive.

If you access `textField.text` when the text field is empty, you get `""` instead of `nil`.

All three attempts of yours check if the text is `nil`. But since a text field's text is almost never `nil`, your guard statements always succeed.

Now you have the variable `f` which contains the value `""`. You pass this to a `Double` initializer. You are basically writing:

```
Double("")!
```

Well, `Double("")` fails and returns `nil`, you then force unwrap it. BOOM!

What you should check instead is an empty string:

```
func returnDouble() -> Double {
    if inputField.text != "" {
        return Double(f)! 
    } else {
        return 0.00 
    }
}
```